# Как перейти по элементу пагинации

Tags: python, парсер, selenium-webdriver

Есть сайт где при переходе на следующую страницу не меняется ссылка, и собственно в элементах пагинации нет атрибута `href` который можно было бы подставить в ссылку и перейти на следующую страницу, но как тогда спарсить все страницы, а не только первую?

Вот условие для нажатия на элемент пагинации:

```
   # Если есть кнопка перехода на следующую страницу, то продолжаем цикл, иначе завершаем
            try:
                a_next_page = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.ajax-button').click()
            except NoSuchElementException:
                break

    finally:
        driver.quit()

    return items
```

Вот сам html/css кнопки:

```css
.catalog-products .pagination .ajax-button {
    display: inline-block;
}
.pagination .ajax-button {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1
px
 solid #e6eef6;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4
px
;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #4982bd;
    padding: 20
px
 0;
}
.ajax-button {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1
px
 solid #e6eef6;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4
px
;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #4982bd;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination-loader"><button type="button" class="ajax-button"><span class="ajax-button-title">еще товары</span></button></div>
```

Вот код парсера, если нужен:

https://dpaste.org/OEPF

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как осуществить переход на следующий элемент пагинации, если не меняется ссылка при переходе на сайте?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1342770/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: Я смог реализовать подобный код для того сайта, но с этим сайтом проблема в том что он просто не видит элемент пагинации и не хочет на него переходить, а как работать с api я вообще понятия не имею

Comment: дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на сайт

Comment: https://atl.ua/search?q=Gazer

Comment: а что не работает в коде с Selenium, который вы написали?

Comment: Он просто бесконечно прогружает первую страницу и ничего больше не происходит

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131032/discussion-between-alexandr-and----ii).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом куске кода вы запускаете бесконечный цикл, где в начале цикла делаете запрос страницы, парсите ее, и если есть кнопка 'показать еще', нажимаете ее. На следующей итерации вы снова запрашиваете заново страницу, естественно она грузится с нуля и вы ее еще раз парсите. Вам нужно один только раз сделать запрос(вынесите из цикла его).

```
 try:
                while True:
                    print('Load:', url)
                    driver.get(url)
        ​
                    for item_el in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("col-inline-xs-3 middle catalog-products-column"):
                        name = item_el.find_element_by_css_selector('.product-micro-title').text
        ​
                        # Не у всех товаров есть цена
                        try:
                            price = item_el.find_element_by_css_selector('.product-micro-price').text
                        except NoSuchElementException:
                            price = '-'
        ​
                        try:nal = item_el.find_element_by_css_selector('.v-price-box__text--out-stock').text
                        except NoSuchElementException:
                            nal = "Есть в наличии"
        ​
                        row = name, price, nal
                        print(row)
                        items.append(row)
        ​
                    # Если есть кнопка перехода на следующую страницу, то продолжаем цикл, иначе завершаем
                    try:
                        a_next_page = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.ajax-button').click()
                    except NoSuchElementException:
                        break
```

Вот так не будет повторно грузить одно и то же:

```
 print('Load:', url)
 driver.get(url)
 try:
                while True:
                    
        ​
                    for item_el in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("col-inline-xs-3 middle catalog-products-column"):
                        name = item_el.find_element_by_css_selector('.product-micro-title').text
        ​
                        # Не у всех товаров есть цена
                        try:
                            price = item_el.find_element_by_css_selector('.product-micro-price').text
                        except NoSuchElementException:
                            price = '-'
        ​
                        try:nal = item_el.find_element_by_css_selector('.v-price-box__text--out-stock').text
                        except NoSuchElementException:
                            nal = "Есть в наличии"
        ​
                        row = name, price, nal
                        print(row)
                        items.append(row)
        ​
                    # Если есть кнопка перехода на следующую страницу, то продолжаем цикл, иначе завершаем
                    try:
                        a_next_page = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.ajax-button').click()
                    except NoSuchElementException:
                        break
```

Comment: В данном случае он код просто прогружает первую страницу и ничего не выводит, просто прогрузка, и  break  некуда поставить, постоянно пишет `break outside loop`

Comment: ваш break в while loop находится, правильно отступы поставили? вам только запрос надо за цикл вынести

Comment: https://dpaste.org/5TaG сделал вот так, break вроде правильно стоит

Comment: [Вот пример правильной разметки](https://dpaste.org/UmL8)

Comment: С break вроде теперь все отлично, но тем не менее, код не хочет прогружать страницы дальше, просто игнорирует кнопку

Comment: a_next_page = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.ajax-button').click()  поменяйте на a_next_page = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.ajax-button')                    a_next_page.click()